# Why does not FSharp.Core.dll contain major version in its name?

Tags: f#

Why does not `FSharp.Core.dll` contain major version in its name? Won't it help to solve binary compatibility issues?

As far as I [understand](https://fsharp.github.io/2015/04/18/fsharp-core-notes.html#libraries-should-target-lower-versions-of-fsharpcore) when authoring a library developed in F# it should have a dependency on `FSharp.Core.dll` NuGet package with upper version limit as `<CurrentMajor+1`. Upper version mustn't stay unconstrained because binary compatibility is guaranteed only between libraries having same major version. Just a [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/) model.

Let's now imagine a library which is useful, has no bugs and logically finished. In other words there is no more need to support it. Period.

Then F# 5 is released and ... users of the library cannot use it anymore in projects referencing libraries created with F# 5.x

---

**Ok, the upper statement is a mistake**
(For `F# 2`, `F# 3` and `F# 4` `FSharp.Core` library had versions `4.x.y.z`.)

Nevertheless, the question stays valid.

At some point in time major version will be increased to `5`. This supposedly will break binary compatibility. (Why otherwise would you make an increment?)

Here is what I mean:
Project references `NuGet.New` and `NuGet.Old`.
`NuGet.Old` references `FSharp.Core.dll` `[4.x.y.z, 5.0.0.0)`
`NuGet.New` references `FSharp.Core.dll` `[5.0.0.0, 6.0.0.0)`
NuGet won't allow it. It is a version conflict.

Actually I confronted with the similar problem yesterday (4th Dec 2018) when EF Core 2.2 NuGet package was already available, but Sdk for `ASP.NET Core` `2.2` did not.

`Micrsofot.AspNetCore.App` metapackage pinned version of `EF Core` to the range `[2.1.0, 2.2.0)`. After I referenced `EF Core` `2.2` in my `DAL` project the whole solution stopped building because of version conflict.

---

However, if it were `FSharp4.Core.dll` and `FSharp5.Core.dll` they could work side by side.

Yes, conventions and shapes of CLR types which represent same concepts of F# 4.x and F# 5.x can differ, but compiler can tag a type with its major version. This will not only help to distinguish new objects from the old ones, but can allow new compiler to silently create code for adapting old types to new version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The major language version is the first number in the package and binary version as of F# 4.5.

FSharp.Core is binary compatible. In your scenario, Users of F# 5 would still be able to use the older library. Failing to do so would be a bug.

Comment: Ok, when will FSharp.Core become 5.x.y.z? Will it be binary compatible with v. 4.x.y.z ?

Comment: Yes, FSharp.Core is designed to be binary compatible. It does not follow semantic versioning.

Comment: `designed to be binary compatible`, that's cool, but how? Are not you afraid of the curse of legacy?

Comment: Working with Scala that includes the major version number in the name it has drawbacks for users. For example; many libraries includes scala major version in their name as well as it is compiled for different scala versions. But if you take that to it it's logical conclusion I guess we should compile a the library for all combinations of all dependency versions.

Comment: @Justanothermetaprogrammer Correct me if I'm wrong, but contrary to `.NET` `JVM` has no means to run side by side multiple classes with same name and package. But in `.NET` assembly name matters. So even if I have same namespaces and class names I am still able to resolve types correctly. So in principle I may decide to have multiple NuGet packages: `MyLib1.dll`, `MyLib2.dll`, `MyLib3.dll`. I can leave them source-compatible, but break binary compatibility. This allows me to use together projects which depend on different versions of MyLib.

Comment: @Justanothermetaprogrammer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern-alias

Comment: @PavelVoronin It is binary compatible because we take great care to ensure no addition to the library or language breaks binary compatibility. This doesn't mean things won't behave differently (e.g., the `Array` module may have more functions in a newer version), but you can always bind to a different version of the library at runtime. This has always been the case as of .NET Framework 4.0.

Comment: @PhillipCarter `we take great care to ensure no addition to the library or language breaks binary compatibility` that's a great challenge I assume. Kudos to the whole F# team.